# Using Message Queue on Windows Mobile 2003

Tags: message-queue, windows-mobile-2003

Does anyone know where I can find the cab file that will allow me to use Microsoft Message Queues on a Windows Mobile 2003 device?

I am writing application that needs to use Microsoft Message Queue on a Windows Mobile 2003 device.

Apparently message queue was never installed on the device.

I have scoured the web and can find no cab files for Msmq for windows mobile 2003. everything reffers to windows mobile 5 and when I try that the setup fails.

Answer (score 0):

My Google-Fu ("windows mobile 2003 msmq") lead me here....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229665(VS.80).aspx

> The Windows Mobile 2003 for Pocket PC SDK provides MSMQ for Pocket PCs running Windows Mobile 2003 for Pocket PC.

and more Google-Fu ("Windows Mobile 2003 for Pocket PC SDK") lead me here...

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9996b314-0364-4623-9ede-0b5fbb133652&displaylang=en

Deploying your app should install what's necessary for MSMQ.

Answer (score 0):

I did that same search among others and have gotten nothing that installed message queuing support to the device.

The closest I came was a suggestion that pointed me to a cab file (msmq.arm.cab or something).
Never found it.

What I am hoping is that someone out there has this cab file or its contents. As I seem to be stuck without them.

Fitzroy